# DotNet XmlSerializer of Lists with constructor

Tags: .net, deserialization, xmlserializer

I have found some unexpected behavior in the XmlSerializer.
If you deserailze a list of objects where the list has a default constructor, the list is appended too.

**Anyone know how to work around this ? 
Here is an example.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace XmlSerialiserTest
{
    public class Schedule
    {
        public Schedule()
        {
            Days = new List<DayOfWeek>() { DayOfWeek.Monday };
            Time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        public List<DayOfWeek> Days { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0},{1}", Time.ToShortTimeString(), string.Join(",", Days));
        }

    }

    public class Schedules
    {
        public List<Schedule> ScheduleList { get; set; }
        public Schedules()
        {
            ScheduleList = new List<Schedule>();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Join(":",ScheduleList);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create a our list of Schedule with one schedule in
            // default constructor will give us Monday by default
            Schedules schedulesOut = new Schedules();
            schedulesOut.ScheduleList.Add(new Schedule());
            // Save
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Schedules));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\xmltest.xml");
            s.Serialize(writer,schedulesOut);
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(schedulesOut);
            // Output is 15:09,Monday
            // Now saved to disk and read back

            TextReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\xmltest.xml");
            Schedules schedulesIn = (Schedules)s.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(schedulesIn);
            // Output is 15:09,Monday,Monday
            // schedulesIn in now contains two Mondays ,not one as expected

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. To be able to 'instantiate' your object, it will always invoke the parameterless constructor. Actually to be able to deserialize you will always need a parameterless  constructor.

Because your constructor creates the list and adds `Monday` as a value al deserialized objects will contain this value by default.

Althrough you can indeed use an array, I would recommend *seperation of concern* and to use a factory method to manually create `Schedule` objects. The factory can then initialize the first value with Monday.

Note that you do need the public parameterless constructor for the deserialization. Usually when using a factory pattern you would want to restrict access to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Change list to array. This works as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace XmlSerialiserTest
{
    public class Schedule
    {
        public Schedule()
        {
           Days = new[] { DayOfWeek.Monday };
           Time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        public DayOfWeek[] Days { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0},{1}", Time.ToShortTimeString(), string.Join(",",     Days));
    }

 }

public class Schedules
{
    public List<Schedule> ScheduleList { get; set; }
    public Schedules()
    {
        ScheduleList = new List<Schedule>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(":",ScheduleList);
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a our list of Schedule with one schedule in
        // default constructor will give us Monday by default
        Schedules schedulesOut = new Schedules();
        schedulesOut.ScheduleList.Add(new Schedule());
        // Save
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Schedules));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\xmltest.xml");
        s.Serialize(writer, schedulesOut);
        writer.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(schedulesOut);
        // Output is 15:09,Monday
        // Now saved to disk and read back

        TextReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\xmltest.xml");
        Schedules schedulesIn = (Schedules) s.Deserialize(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(schedulesIn);
        // Output is 15:09,Monday,Monday
        // schedulesIn in now contains two Mondays ,not one as expected

    }
}
```

}